# Image uploading with laravel: file uploaded but it is not image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to insert the name, image and score of the user in `results` table. Score is calculated by comparing correct answer from `quiz` table. Everything is fine with other data but with image something is uploaded but it is not image with name jpg?

this is how i use the form to submit in a view.

```
  <form method="POST" action="{{url("quiz/check/{$quiz[0]->category}/2")}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and the route is:

```
Route::post('/quiz/check/{name}/{no}', 'playquiz@check');
```

the controller:

```
     public function check(Request $request, $name, $no)
  {

    $count=0; 
    $input=$request->all();
    $mycheck=$input['mycheck'];
    $eman=$input['name'];

        $stmt = quiz::where('category',$name)->where('level',$no)->get();
        $array=['category'=>$name,'level'=>$no];            
        $cat = quiz::where($array)->first();  

    foreach ($stmt as $c)
    {

         if(array_key_exists($c->qid, $mycheck) && $mycheck[$c->qid]==$c->answer)
            {
                $count=$count+1;
        }
    }

        $imageName = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->file('image')->move(
        base_path() . '/public/images/', $imageName);


   $addscore= Result::insert(['Name'=>$eman,'Score'=>$count,'Level'=>$no,'Category'=> $name,'Image'=>$imageName]);

        return View('quiz.check',['stmt'=>$stmt,'input'=>$input,'count'=>$count,'eman'=> $eman,'cat'=>$cat,'mycheck'=>$mycheck,'addscore'=>$addscore]);  

 }
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non object on what line?

Comment: Also shouldn't `$request->file('image')->move` be `$request->file('image')->move(` ?

Answer (score 1):

This part `$stmt=DB::select('select * from results');` will results in array, that is the problem.

The other problem is that You are using `DB`. Why write queries Yourself when Laravel offers eloquent?

You should use models for Your object like `Result`. Then You can simply access all values like so: `Result::all()` and so on.

My suggestion for You, is to read some tutorials or even better start from laracasts beginner series!

Comment: As you suggested I am now using eloquent and learned some tutorials but struck here. i've updated the question now.